# Should the [dwv] tag be a synonym of a new [drain-waste-vent] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We had some questions edited today to add the [dwv](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwv) tag.  My understanding is that Stack Exchange generally prefers [tags not be abbreviations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/146318):

> When naming a tag, think about how someone would google that subject. In most cases this means typing out the full name, but you may also want to use the abbreviation. For example, "css" is probably more appropriate than "cascading-style-sheets".

DWV is a well-known term in the plumbing trade, and the first hit in a Google search for DWV is the Wikipedia article for [Drain-waste-vent system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system).

So, should we create a [drain-waste-vent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drain-waste-vent) tag and have [dwv](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwv) be a synonym of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While DWV is very standard term (the Home Depot near me uses it on a big sign near the pipe), novice plumbers probably do not know it.  Once the tag is on a question I don't think the abbreviation is too confusing since there is a detailed tool tip that describes it in detail. However, many plumbing drainage questions get the "drain" tag but never get the DWV tag until it is edited by somone who knows about it.

I like the idea of actually spelling it out as I think it might help new people find the tag more easily. When they start adding a "drain" tag it will also show the new "drain-waste-vent" tag and they might actually choose it.

When I initially created the DWV tag is was to help differentiate questions related to "venting".  I wanted to be able to tag plumbing vent questions with a different tag than the "vent" tag that people use for just regular air ventaliation questions.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reasoning behind the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this makes sense. I've created the new [drain-waste-vent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drain-waste-vent) tag, auujay handled the tag wiki (thanks!), and the tags have now been merged with a synonym pointing anyone from [dwv](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwv) to the new tag.

Comment: Based on auujay's answer, I think syonymizing might be the better option.